# Laravel eloquent Выбрать по условию

Tags: php, база-данных, laravel

Есть таблица users и расширяющая people таблица.  Необходимо выбрать пользователей  users где people поле help = need;

```
   public function person()
  {

    return $this->hasOne('App\Person','user_id');
  }



в контроллере пытался так но ошибка 
      $users_want=User::with('pepole')->where('pepole.help','want')->get();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно использовать метод `whereHas`, тогда всё отработает.

```
$users_want = User::with('pepole')->whereHas('pepole', function ($query) {
   $query->where('help', 'want');
})->get();
```

Comment: Большое спасибо мил человек ! :)